# Whats wrong with indentation of Python if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have

```
if p != None && (self.running == None or self.running < p):                 
    self.preempt(p)
```

What's wrong with the indentation?

Comment: Nothing. What makes you think something is wrong with the indentation?

Comment: In the short snippet you showed, nothing. Please add more context and the (full) error message. As an aside, you should use `is` and `is not` to check for `None`, and `&&` must be a typo.

Comment: What do you think `&&` is?  It's not operator I've ever seen.  Why is it in your code snippet?  It's not in this list.  http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators.Why it is in your code?

Comment: Wow, people need to calm down on the down-votes for this guy. The indentation is fine on this; but he did have something else incorrect which he wouldn't have learned without posting.

Comment: @TJBiddle helping people out properly requires that they first properly report the problem. Further, good questions are ones that will help people who Google search in the future and find the SO question and answer. People who run into this problem in the future are unlikely to be searching for help with indentation because they are unlikely to conclude that the indentation is wrong. Especially given that the error message will (a) say nothing about indentation; (b) **literally point directly to the `&&` symbol**.

Comment: -1 You forgot to include the error message.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax error, and is unlikely to be useful to future users

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `and` instead of `&&`.

Also [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

So result should be:

```
if p is not None and (self.running is None or self.running < p):
    self.preempt(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it doesn't match the indentation of previous statements (you may be mixing tabs and spaces, or the indentation may not be the same amount as previous statements). The rest of the code and your actual error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually trying this produces an error message something like:

- if the source is in a file:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "test.py", line 1
      if x && y:
            ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```
- if the source is typed in:

  ```
    File "<stdin>", line 1
      if x && y: pass
            ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```

In both cases, notice how the `^` points at `&&`? That's because `&&` is invalid syntax (like the message says). It has nothing to do with indentation (like the message doesn't say).

Comment: I got an error about indentation tho, but it was fixed by @gawi answer. Perhaps its something to do with code before this or something